# Cloud Firestore OR query

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How do I fetch multiple documents from firebase? I want to fetch all of the documents that are in a list.

I can only run the below query if instead of a list I pass it a single item for the owner field since isMemberOf is not a real operator. I put it there as something that I imagine it might look like.

Right now I can only pass a single value and use isEqualTo: instead of my made up operator.

How do I do this?

```dart
 Stream<List<Event>> subscribeToEventsByDates(
      List<String> users, DateTime start, DateTime end) {
    return Firestore.instance
        .collection('events')
 ----> SELECT * (all that match) <------- doesn't exist? How to do this?
        .where('owner', isMemberOf: users) 
        .where('start', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: start)
        .where('start', isLessThanOrEqualTo: end)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.documents
            .map((event) => Event.fromJson(event.data))
            .toList());
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass an array of strings to a filter to match any one of them for a given field, that's called an ["in" query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any).

The [API documentation for where()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/where.html) suggsets that you should use "whereIn" for that.

```
.where('owner', whereIn: users)
```

From the [documentation on `in` queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any):

> Use the `in` operator to combine up to 10 equality (`==`) clauses on the same field with a logical `OR`.